# Modify titlebar buttons

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, tweak-tool

I am running Elementary OS Loki and I love it! I have downloaded tweaks and have changed my icons to the numix ones. However, I would like to change the buttons to look more like the ones on Mac OS but not change the rest. I have downloaded this: https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/OS+X+El+Capitan+(GTK,+Unity+&+Cinnamon)?content=174139 and have tried to take some parts from the CSS files and move them over to a copy of the elementary theme, but I do not know what to edit. I tried to modify the buttons-section in the gtk-widgets.css file without much success. So, I now ask you for any solutions.